# Error while opening application via terminal?

Tags: command-line, 18.04

When I open any application like firefox from terminal, it opens but before that in the terminal it shows

```
(firefox:2292): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:20:38.765: Theme parsing error: gtk-main.css:73:38: Failed to import: Error opening file /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.20/apps/gnome-builder.css: No such file or directory
```

What is this and how to fix this?

Comment: While the line mentioned in this bug report does not exist in my 18.04 install read thru this bug report & see if workaround 'fixes' for you. (or if line exists you could try removing it.. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-themes/+bug/1773045

Comment: Well thanks for the link but as it is stated that may not be a permanent fix for the solution.

Comment: I use ambiance but did just ck. radiance & yeah the warning exists. (it's just a warning, no big deal..) Looking closer the line does exist, I used nano to remove it, that solves the issue. (ambiance does not have this line.) So just edit it out, i.e `sudo nano  /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.20/gtk-main.css` or `sudo -H gedit /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.20/gtk-main.css`  , arrow down to line 73 & remove the line. `

Comment: Yes thanks even I thought about that. Thank you very much hope it doesn't disturb me anymore.

Answer (score 0):

For me it seems that you have edited some theme CSS files (as [`gtk-main.css`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=gtk-main.css&mode=exactfilename&suite=bionic&arch=any) from Radiance theme).

You can reinstall them with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall light-themes
```

Comment: Well I tried that but same issue persists.